# How do I add unallocated space to another partition

Tags: ubuntu-mate

How do I add the unallocated space to sdb2?

There are a few mysteries about Gparted. :-)

The 96 Gbytes.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to backup all data, reformat the drive, and put the data back.

Answer (score 1):

Your unallocated space is living on a Extended (Another) partition.

1. Get a backup from `/dev/sdb5`.
2. delete `/dev/sdb5`.
3. delete `/dev/sdb3`.
4. Get a backup from `/dev/sdb2`.
5. Resize (Extend) `/dev/sdb2`.
6. Create a new "2G" primary partition (instead of your old `/dev/sdb5`).

Answer (score 1):

sdb2 is a primary partition. sdb3 is an extended partition with a small partition inside it, sdb5, and the unallocated space. You cannot move the unallocated space directly to sdb2. Do you need sdb5? If not move the contents elsewhere, backup any other important data on sdb and using GParted:

1. Delete sdb5
2. Delete sdb3
3. Unmount sdb2
4. Extend sdb2 into the unallocated space.

If you want to keep sdb5:

1. Shrink sdb3 as much as you can
2. Move sdb5 as far as possible to the right
3. Unmount sdb2
4. Extend sdb2 into the unallocated space

Hope this helps